# I need to count the number of clicks on two buttons and then a percentage list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to count the number of clicks on two buttons and then a percentage list
I have a problem with passing str (self.counter)
to 3 functions which are to divide one function by another and show it as a percentage result

```
self.counter = 0

def clicked():
    self.counter += 1
    L['text'] = 'Poprawnie: ' + str(self.counter)

self.counter2 = 0

def clicked2():
    self.counter2 += 1
    R['text'] = 'Niepoprawnie: ' + str(self.counter2)
        
def clickedSum():
    a_number = str(self.counter) / str(self.counter2)
    percentage = "{:.2%}".format(a_number)
    print(percentage)
```

Comment: Are these functions part of a class? From your example, its not clear what `self` is associated with. Typically, `self` is used in Python to refer to an object of some class.

Answer (score 0):

If this is part of a class (as it has self reference, I assume it to be), you might have to initiate your two counters in the **init** to avoid they will be class-variables instead of instance-variables.

like so:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.counter = 0
    ...

def clicked():
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I managed to write, I will leave it if someone has a similar problem;)

```
self.counter = 0
self.counter2 = 0

def clicked():
    self.counter += 1
    L['text'] = 'True: ' + str(self.counter)

def clicked2():
    self.counter2 += 1
    R['text'] = 'False: ' + str(self.counter2)

def clicked3():
    S['text'] = 'All click: ' + str(self.counter / (self.counter2 + self.counter)) + '%'

S = Label(self, text="All:0%")
S.pack()
    
b = Button(self, text="True", padx=35, pady=10, fg="#ffffff", bg="#263942", command=lambda: [clicked(), clicked3()])
b.pack(side="right")

L = Label(self, text="True:0")
L.pack(side="right")

b2 = Button(self, text="False", padx=35, pady=10, fg="#ffffff", bg="#263942", command=lambda: [clicked2(), clicked3()])
b2.pack(side="left")

R = Label(self, text="False:0")
R.pack(side="left")
```